# nested ngfor is not updating when I add data to the sub list array in angular 4

Tags: angular, ngfor

here is my code

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <div *ngFor="let data of item"></div>
</div>
```

when I update the item then the data is not updating on html page. Do anybody has any idea? Thanks

Comment: What does the code like you use to update `item` and where is it called from? Does it update if you modify `items` at the same place?

Comment: yes it works if I update items

Comment: Can you try to reproduce in http://stackblitz.com?